# Visual Studio 2012 "Visual C# class" template location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, itemtemplate, class-template

I'm currently able to modify the default class template at the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class
```

This works great when right-clicking on a project and selecting `add -> class`.

Though, when adding a class through the `File` menu item of Visual Studio

```
File -> New -> File... -> Visual C# Class
```

The class template appears to not work. I'm assuming it's at a different location from where I've specified above. Where can I find the "**Visual C# class**" template?

**Edit:**

class generated from `File->New->File... General -> Visual C# class`

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }
}
```

class generated from `right-clicking on project-> Add Clas`s

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, the classes are different all together, which makes me believe that it is using two different templates.

Comment: did you delete and rebuild your templates cache?

Comment: yes.. I'm running devenv /setup after changing the file. should I delete the entire templatecache folder first?

Comment: Yes, you need to delete the ItemTemplatesCache dir and then run `devenv /installvstemplates` for it to regen all templates

Comment: Yeah, I deleted it. still nothing. it appears to be using an entirely different template all together since there's only one using statement for the class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the same with VS 2012, but I think you can tell VS to regenerate the cache using the command `devenv /installvstemplates` (provided you run the command as administrator).

More complete explanation (for VS 2010) here:
http://ericsowell.com/blog/2007/5/22/how-to-edit-visual-studio-templates

Comment: I've done that. I believe that VS is using a different class template for when classes are generated through the file->new menu item

Comment: D'oh. I'll see if I can come up with anything useful when I'm back near a VS 2012 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much as an answer to the where, but to the why...

It looks like `File->New->File` doesn't use the template, I have tested this and it's the case with VS2010 too.  On a side note, why don't you use `right-clicking on project-> Add Class`?  It works and let's you place the file where you need it to be, note that the other method opens the file, but doesn't add it to the project, merely opens it.  Perhaps that's part of the reason why it is such a basic empty class template.

To be honest this is the first time I try the other method you mentioned :)

Comment: I do use the second method you've described and that works fine.. I was just testing the template out and realized it didn't work using the method I described above.

Comment: @moncada yeah seems it doesn't use the template we are acustomed to, and it doesn't even add the file to the actual project or solution, at least that was the case for me on VS2010, I don't have VS2012 on this machine to confirm this is also true for 2012